# Migrating Compute Engine activity logs to Cloud Audit logs - (Google Cloud)

Tags: migration, google-compute-engine, audit-logging, activitylog

We recently received an email from Google Cloud informing us of the upcoming shutdown of Compute Engine activity logs, and instructing us to migrate our logs to Cloud Audit logs.

After reading through the documentation, it was not completely clear to me how automatized this migration is...

I understood:

- Cloud Audit Logs has 3 types of logs: Admin Activity, Data Access and System Events logs.
- Admin Activity logs are automatically setup and free
- Data Access must be setup and have a cost
- Compute Engine instances have limited Data Access logs applicable: only ADMIN_READ, and DATA_READ (this one only applicable for instance.getSerialPortOutput logs)

My **questions**:

- How do I setup System Events logs?
- How do I check whether any of our current Compute Engine activity logs are to become Cloud Audit Data Access logs? (so I can know that I have to set them up)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this migration guide https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs ? You can find there that "To use audit logs instead of activity logs, adjust your queries." by following steps https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs#how_to_migrate_from_activity_logs_to_audit_logs . As I can see at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#system-event "System Event audit logs are always written; you can't configure or disable them.". Please change your question if you need more details.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Thanks. Yes, I did check the guide as it came in the informative email, but being a new whole infrastructure to me, I find the info very inconclusively laid out and unclearly formulated as it leaves doubts whether there's other methods or tasks to take care of. Hence I needed verificaton from someone who has experience.... Also, where can I find the old log queries if not in the Stackdriver logging console? (+ console is in Spanish (Spanish client) and it seems like if I change display lang, it will be so for other users...THUMBS UP IF THEY FACILITATE TEMP. LANG CHANGE)

Comment: If some examples aren't clear enough or not available for some particular features, or need to be improved you can use press `Send feedback` and ask for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation [System Event audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#system-event):

> **System Event audit logs are always written; you can't configure or
>   disable them**. There is no charge for your System Event audit logs.

Accordingly to the documentation [Migrating from activity logs to audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs):

> **Compute Engine activity logs are to be deprecated on Sep 30, 2020**.
>   Some activity log entries will be discontinued on June 1, 2020.

as result, it's better to migrate before deprecation date.

In addition, you can find in the migration [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs) that:

> **To use audit logs instead of activity logs, adjust your [queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces)**. Use
>   the following [steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs#how_to_migrate_from_activity_logs_to_audit_logs):
>
> 1. **Find your old queries**. For example, you might have saved them in a
>      saved search in the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?_ga=2.29416319.1173686192.1581927650-712562018.1576172652) or created a script using the API or
>      SDK. For more information about how you can monitor your resources,
>      see the [Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) docs.
> 2. **Replace the activity log fields with appropriate audit log fields**.
>      Refer to the [table](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/migrating-from-activity-logs-to-audit-logs#log_entry_field_mappings) to see how the fields map to each other.

If some instructions or examples in the documentation aren't clear enough or not available for some particular features, or could be improved you can use press `Send feedback` button at the end of the page and ask for improvements.